# Re-Render some data on the same template

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsrender

I have a scenario where-in by-default I would be rendering some data from JSON on my JSP page. Now, I want to achieve a use-case wherein when I click on some menu-item it would trigger a function and that should in response update the template with the relevant data.

So for initial loading I am loading the data from JSON using:

```
$.getJSON( "/somelocation/test.json", function( data ) {
    console.log(data); //json output 
    var template = $.templates("#theContent");
    var htmlOutput = template.render(data, {selectedValue: "abc"});
    $("#mainBody").html(htmlOutput);
});
```

Now I write the same logic in a function which will be triggered on the menu item click then on the JSP page I just see "#theContent" as an output. Can you please suggest what might be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a string to `$.templates(someString)`, then JsRender will first attempt to treat it as a jQuery selector. If jQuery is loaded and the selector does return a script element for a template then [that template will be used](https://www.jsviews.com/#d.templates@fromscriptblock).

If the string is not valid selector or does not return a script element for a template block, then JsRender will fall back on [treating the string as template markup](https://www.jsviews.com/#d.templates@tmpl-string).

You can test in the context of your code whether `$("#theContent")` does return a non-empty jQuery object. (`$("#theContent").length === 1`). It looks as if in your code it is not finding a script element with ID `"theContent"`.